# Core data Math?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a core data application.  It allows the user to enter a job, then for that job they can enter equipment info, then for that equipment, they can enter parts for the equipment, and simultaneously that same part shows up under the job part list.

My problem is that when the user enters the same part under 2 different pieces of equipment, for the same job, I want the job part list to update its quantity.  Right now it simply shows up as a duplicate under 2 tableview cells, leaving the user to have to add up the quantity manually.

Is there a way to allow the `NSFetchedResultsController` - perhaps through a predicate - to do the math automatically and use only 1 cell...simply updating the quantity?

Any suggestions are worth trying at this point...I'm officially stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do part of this with the `NSFetchRequest` you assign your `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Check the documentation for:

```
- (void)setPropertiesToGroupBy:(NSArray *)array
- (void)setReturnsDistinctResults:(BOOL)values
```

If you fetch all parts and group by the part #, and only return distinct values, you’ll get one result for each part #. However, I haven’t figured out how to show the actual part count yet.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding your model would help here because its not clear what you mean by "enter parts for the equipment" 
- does this CREATE a new managedObject for each required part?
- or does this simply create a reference between equipment and part, such that every time you do this you create a reference to the same part?

I would create a RequiredPart entity and have a reference to Part to identify the type of part that is required.  So you would have something like

Job ->> Equipment ->> RequiredPart - Part

Then in your predicate using collection operators such as @sum, @count etc. (possibly in conjunction with setPropertiesToGroupBy) to get the quantity.

Here is a link for an explanation of how to do a group by queryhttp://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/ios-core-data-group-by-and-count-results/